# Vue 3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'item' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to use [@yeger/vue-masonry-wall](https://github.com/DerYeger/vue-masonry-wall) in a Vue3/Vite3 project. When I run yarn dev I get the above error message. I am using @yeger/vue-masonry-wall in a Nuxt3 project, so now I am not sure, what is causing this error.

**.src/components/MasonryGallery.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const items = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    description: 'The first item.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    description: 'The second item.'
  },
]
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="items">
    <masonry-wall :items="items" :ssr-columns="1" :column-width="300" :gap="16">
      <template #default="{ item, index }">
        <div :style="{ height: `${index * 100}px` }">
          <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
          <span>{{ item.description }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
    </masonry-wall>
  </div>
```

**./src/App.vue**

```
<script setup>
import MasonryGallery from "./components/MasonryGallery.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <MasonryGallery />
  </div>
</template>
```

**./src/main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import MasonryWall from '@yeger/vue-masonry-wall'

import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App).mount('#app');

app.use(MasonryWall)
```

I am using:

- "vue": "^3.2.37"
- "vite": "^3.0.4"
- node 18.7.0

I also tried adding this to the build property in defineConfig:

```
transpile: ['@yeger/vue-masonry-wall'],
```

**Stacktrace**

```
at MasonryGallery.vue:17:29
    at renderFnWithContext (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:853:21)
    at normalizeChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6925:42)
    at createBaseVNode (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6678:9)
    at _createVNode (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6780:12)
    at createVNodeWithArgsTransform (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6636:12)
    at Proxy._sfc_render (MasonryGallery.vue:16:5)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:896:44)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5580:57)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
```

Comment: The error is caused by Masonry providing `undefined` value to the scoped default slot. You will have to debug the component/library in the browser in find out why it binds `undefined` on line 17 in `MasonryGallery.vue`